# Why I can't install TomCat 8 on this Ubuntu 15.04 system? (I obtain an error when I perform chmod statment)

Tags: server, permissions, 15.04, chmod, tomcat

I am not yet a Linux guy and I am finding some difficulties trying to install **TomCat 8** on an Ubuntu 15.04 system that I have to use as development environment.

So I am following this tutorial (I don't know if it is a good tutorial...): http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/21/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-32-64bit-gnulinux-easy-visual-guide/

So I have downloaded the **apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz** file from TomCat website and I have extract it.

Now as shown in the tutorial I try to perform this statmet:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/Scaricati$ sudo chmod -R root:root /apache-tomcat*
```

but I obtain this error message:

```
chmod: modo non valido: "root:root"
```

that in english should be sometning like **chmod mode not allowed** (or something like this).

What could be the problem? How can I correctly install TomCat 8 on my Ubuntu 15.04 system? What exactly does the previous statment?

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chmod` will change the permissions, while `chown` will change the owner and group of a file. In this case you're erroneously using `chmod` where you should be using `chown`.

This is an error in the tutorial you're following, you didn't really do anything wrong but the instructions were mistaken. I suggest you find a book on basic Unix commands so you can learn them, and then you'll be able to catch these basic mistakes on your own.